# Minify the React build files to make them hard to read

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, minify, uglifyjs

I have created the React application with create-react-app and make build. I see some js files which are minified, but when I check them in Chrome Dev Tools they look almost non-changed in "beautify" mode "{}" (the same variable names, etc). Map files are removed.

Is there a simple way to make variable names shortened for example a,b,c,d,e,f... etc like "p,a,c,k,e,r" tool does for example?

Thank you!

Here is a dump of build process

```
d:\folder\jvgs4>npm run build

> VGS4@4.2.7 build d:\folder\jvgs4
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
Compiled with warnings.

...some warning messages

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  89.42 KB (-46 B)  build\static\js\2.594b29a3.chunk.js
  54.46 KB (-42 B)  build\static\js\3.c2f4981f.chunk.js
  22.89 KB (-44 B)  build\static\js\4.e7fba51b.chunk.js
  3.31 KB (-41 B)   build\static\js\main.89abc980.chunk.js
  1.17 KB (-49 B)   build\static\css\main.70a8ce85.chunk.css
  1.14 KB (-42 B)   build\static\js\runtime-main.0bbc6d46.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at https://api.zxlab.org/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

......
```

And here is a screenshot of js code I have

https://e-wm.org/i/E20210408-002337-001.png

Comment: They should be minified by default (webpack build) in production build. Can you please add a screenshot and the compilation command? Note that source map files are enabled for production by default... https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

Comment: are you sure your looking at the production build ?

Comment: I've added some listings to the first message, could you check?